# How to set phpinfo() and php --ini in CLI use same php.ini file?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ubuntu

How to set `phpinfo()` and `php --ini` in CLI use same `php.ini` file?

Laravel PHP

```
dd(phpinfo());
```

[image]

in CLI

```
php --ini
```

result:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.4/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
```

How to set the php.ini same with browser and cli?

because I installed an PHP extension but can't find it in php debug using this code `get_loaded_extensions();` but PHP extension is on the list in CLI when I run `php -m`

Comment: Please do not repost questions.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Deleted the previous question. Please answer the question.

Comment: We probably need more information about your PHP set up. You've tagged this as Ubuntu but screenshot shows RHEL--is it from the actual system? Can you confirm you want this for PHP builtin web server (and not other servers like Nginx or Apache?). It also won't hurt to explain what exact problem you're trying to fix, because there might be better solutions that fiddling with your PHP packages.

Comment: For what it's worth, builtin server accepts `-c` to provide a directory to look for php.ini.